# Как проверить есть ли совпадения в тексте?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Необходимо выполнить проверку текста на наличие совпадений

```
    RegExp.escape = function(text) {
    return text.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");
}

function InsertText(){
    var str = RegExp.escape(editor.getValue()); 
    var res = new RegExp(RegExp.escape('<?echo htmlspecialchars_decode($check, ENT_QUOTES)?>'), 'g');
    res = new RegExp(res);

document.getElementById('bg-primary').innerHTML = res;
alert(res.exec(str));

if(res.test(str)){
    $("#next").show();
}
else{
    $("#next").hide();
   }

}
```

Нужно узнать есть ли в переменной **str** какое либо значение которое присутствует в переменной **res**. И если есть то вывести кнопку.
Наличие RegExp.escape обязательно.
В коде который представлен выше выводиться ошибка: res.test is not a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю решение заключается в этом:

Замените вашу строку *var res* на приведенную ниже.

```
var res = new RegExp('<?echo htmlspecialchars_decode($check, ENT_QUOTES)?>', 'g');
```

Или вот полностью рабочий код для вас:

```
RegExp.escape = function(text) {
    return text.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");
}

function InsertText(){
    var str = RegExp.escape(editor.getValue()); 
    var res = new RegExp('<?echo htmlspecialchars_decode($check, ENT_QUOTES)?>', 'g');

if(res.test(str)){
    $("#next").show();
} else {
    $("#next").hide();
}

}
```

Comment: Проблема с "res.test is not a function" ушла но теперь вообще не получается найти соответствия.

Comment: Попробуйте после преобразования к _RegExp_ выполнить этот код:
`alert(res.exec(str));`

Comment: Проверил, вывело null

Comment: @yaslik однозначно что-то не так с _str.replace_. Вы там вообще помоему результат заменяете на ""(ничего)

Comment: Да нет, не заменяем.Обновил код в примере с учетом ваших изменений.

Comment: @yaslik Сейчас посидел на JSFiddle и поковырял. Похоже что дело в _escape_ или в _htmlspecialchars_. Скидываю то [что наковырял](https://jsfiddle.net/rjnye4ch/)

Comment: я видимо немного немного правильно объяснил, точнее не дополнил, мы в str не ищем `<?echo htmlspecialchars_decode($check, ENT_QUOTES)?>` там эхом выводиться допусти слово "задумался" вот именно это слово мы и должны проверить на вхождение в str.

Comment: @yaslik я обновил пример на fiddle по вашему объяснению, гляньте, может вы увидите ошибку, вам все таки виднее работа вашего кода
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rjnye4ch/1/)

Comment: Все верно, только не могу понять почему при RegExp.escape выдает ошибку.

Comment: @yaslik окей, вот вам еще код, так должно быть максимально понятно
[Задумался](https://jsfiddle.net/rjnye4ch/4/)

Comment: @yaslik и я обновил ответ, думаю теперь это то что вам нужно

Comment: Сейчас все отлично только если проверка выполняется по одному слову допусти "задумался", если же присутствуют спец.символы или же это фраза "Я очень сильно задумался", то ничего не происходит.

Comment: @yaslik только что проверил, и у меня все сработало, смотрите сами - [тут](https://jsfiddle.net/rjnye4ch/5/)

Comment: вот что у меня получается если я хочу допустим проверить код [ТУТ](https://jsfiddle.net/0m01g5vw/)
В результате False

Comment: @yaslik Уберите escape и все будет работать. Проблема в нем. [Смотрите](https://jsfiddle.net/0m01g5vw/1/). P.S. Обновил ответ

Comment: Да, все теперь отлично))
Огромное спасибо)))